# How can i get the value of the selected option using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a custom select box and i wanted to get the value of the selected label, when i click at the button "check" i get an alert saying that shows the code inside the div which seems logical, the question is how can i get the value or the text of the option selected.

```css
.selectbox_newpost {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color:#FFF;
}

.selectbox_newpost {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
}

.option_newpost {
  padding:0 30px 0 10px;
  min-height:40px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background:#333;
  border-top:#222 solid 1px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events:none;
  order:2;
  z-index:1;
  transition:background .4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesss.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function clicked(){
  var option = document.getElementById("selectedOptionNewpost");
  alert(option.innerHTML);
}
</script>

  <div class="selectbox_container_newpost">
    <div id="selectedOptionNewpost" class="selectbox_newpost" tabindex="1">
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt1" checked>
    <label for="opt1" class="option_newpost">Objects</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt2">
    <label for="opt2" class="option_newpost">Vehicules</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt3">
    <label for="opt3" class="option_newpost">Technology</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt4">
    <label for="opt4" class="option_newpost">Books</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt5">
    <label for="opt5" class="option_newpost">Furniture</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt6">
    <label for="opt6" class="option_newpost">Others...</label>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="clicked()">Check</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For this you could have used `select`. Then it would be much easier for you to find the selected option.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: @decpk there are lots of reasons not to use the `<select>` mechanism. It is generally considered to be extremely unfriendly to users.

Comment: @Pointy What is that so? Just curious...

Comment: @decpk it's easy for programmers like us to use, but for normal people it's  weird and not obvious. There have been usability studies that have demonstrated that.

Comment: @Pointy 'select' extremly unfriendly? is one the most used controls in html after input, and very straight forward in use for a list longer then 5 items. whats the alternative?

Comment: Lots of discussion and examples here [Striking a Balance Between Native and Custom Select Elements](https://css-tricks.com/striking-a-balance-between-native-and-custom-select-elements/). Without knowing your implementation of the actual `select` functionality this is hard to answer.

Comment: @Etienne yes it is very commonly used, but that does not make it good for ordinary people. And they're *really* bad in mobile/touchscreen browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the selected radio button and then the label associated with it and print out the textContent.

Check below

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```css
.selectbox_newpost {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color:#FFF;
}

.selectbox_newpost {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
}

.option_newpost {
  padding:0 30px 0 10px;
  min-height:40px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background:#333;
  border-top:#222 solid 1px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events:none;
  order:2;
  z-index:1;
  transition:background .4s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesss.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function clicked(){
  var option = document.getElementById("selectedOptionNewpost");
  const radioSelected = option.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked")

  const labelForSelectedRadio = option.querySelector(`label[for=${radioSelected.getAttribute('id')}]`)
  console.log(labelForSelectedRadio.textContent)
}
</script>

  <div class="selectbox_container_newpost">
    <div id="selectedOptionNewpost" class="selectbox_newpost" tabindex="1">
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt1" checked>
    <label for="opt1" class="option_newpost">Objects</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt2">
    <label for="opt2" class="option_newpost">Vehicules</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt3">
    <label for="opt3" class="option_newpost">Technology</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt4">
    <label for="opt4" class="option_newpost">Books</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt5">
    <label for="opt5" class="option_newpost">Furniture</label>
    <input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt6">
    <label for="opt6" class="option_newpost">Others...</label>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="clicked()">Check</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you use JQuery:

```
function clicked(){
    alert($("input[type=radio][name=test]:checked").attr('id'));
    alert($("input[type=radio][name=test]:checked").attr('value'));
}
```

But you have to add a value attribute to the radiobutton:

```
<input class="selectopt" name="test" type="radio" id="opt4" value="4">
```